# asp.net replacing sql collation specific characters

Tags: asp.net, character, collation, turkish

Regardless of the sql database collation being used is there any way to replace the special characters when displayed in the interface. At least is there any way to implement that for the "Turkish I" so discussed here :-) I want to eliminate small dotless 'i'.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple String.Replace for the characters you dont want?

You can either keep the original data in the database and do this when the page renders or you can do this before saving the data to the database.

Comment: Well it can be considered as a solution, a good one in fact while querying from the database but you have to specify for each character to be subsituted. So not optimal. In my case it works because so far I am only interested in replacing 'i' but in general it is not optimal solution.

Comment: I meant, after the query from the database, ie in C#, you could then run through all the characters you want to replace?